# How can I avoid using the full yaml route for a locales translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, internationalization, locale

I'm working on a view managed by `Admin::AccountPresetCustomFieldsController` controller.

I have the partials folder `views/admin/account_preset_custom_fields/partials` and I'm trying to translate a file stored inside that folder but I can't manage to do something like `t(".field_to_be_translated")` but have to resort to specifying the whole route like so: `t("admin.account_preset_custom_fields.partials.partial_file_name.field_to_be_translated)` .

My `controller.en.yml` looks like this:

```
en:
  admin:
    account_preset_custom_fields:
      partials:
        partial_file_name:
          field_to_be_translated: Translation
```

I'm confused because in other parts of our App I can just do `t(".field_to_be_translated")` and, providing the indentation in the `.yml` is correct, it will pick the translation right away.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think partials cannot be in a subfolder, Rails looks in admin/account_preset_custom_fields/partial_file_name/field_to_be_translated, so move the partials up one directory and remove the partials: in the yaml

Comment: @LesNightingill I actually have the same schema for a modal window that is inside a partials folder so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks.

Comment: is the modal window a partial? If it is, then you're right, the directory structure is probably not the problem. However ActionView has a particular convention regarding partials. Anyway it's quick to try and see, right?

Comment: @LesNightingill well I moved the files outside of the partials folder where the Index and other action view files are located and it still doesn't pick up the translation. I updated the yaml schema removing the partials key, but it still won't work. I'm more confused than before. Double checked the key matches the controller name.

Comment: if you put a debugger statement in the partial, and break during the view rendering, then in the console that appears when the code hits the debugger statement, you can type translate(".") and you will see all the yaml, rendered as a hash, that are available in the context of the partial. Does this give you any insight?

Comment: if the test above does not show any translations available, try deleting 'admin:' in the yaml file and promoting its contents up one level. I'm unsure how namespacing ('admin') is factored into the evaluation of the default translations for a partial.

Comment: if you _really_ want to get into the weeds, puts a t(".foo") in your view and then put a breakpoint in the `scope_key_by_partial` method of action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb. This is where the evaluation of the partial occurs.